# Can it be plagiarism to copy pseudocode into python?

Tags: plagiarism

I'm reading a paper that describes an algorithm in pseudocode, and I copied it into Python for a project I'm working on. However, now that I'm looking at it, the Python code is remarkably similar to the pseudocode in the paper. Could this be considered plagiarism?

Comment: Do you plan on publishing the Python code as your own work?

Answer (score 4):

The key piece of what sets plagiarism apart from appropriate use of what you find in the literature is to claim the work as your own. If you find an algorithm in pseudocode and translate it into Python, add a comment of the form

```
  # The following is an adaptation of the algorithm found in
  # Smith et al., "A new way of sorting numbers 
  # in O(sqrt(N)) operations", Journal of Improbable Algorithms,
  # vol. 42, 2022.
```

to the top of your file. This way it's clear what is yours and what is not, and you're on the safe side!

Comment: Yes, that big O for a sort would be very improbable.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton I'm just glad at least one person saw it ;-)